# GA conversion tracking

Tags: events, google-analytics, ads, tracking

I have set up goal tracking on GA for my website. I can see the goals reported in the real-time overview as well as under Conversions/Goals. But when I want to see the multi-channel funnel report, like assisted conversions or attribution model comparison, I cannot select the goals from the "Conversions" field. It is simply empty. Does it take much time for the goals events to appear in conversions or should I take other steps I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Time delay is about 24-48 hours.